# How to set values in FactoryGirl for nested structure

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I'm using Factory Girl with traits, and trying to figure out how to set the 'answer' value below:

```
factory :example_factory do
    user 'TEST'
    id 'blah'
end

trait :example_trait do
questions [
              {
                  question: "blah",
                  answer: "#{answer}"
              },
          ]
end
```

I've tried the following, but keep running into "ArgumentError: trait not registered: answer".

```
FactoryGirl.build(:example, :example_trait, answer: 'custom')
```

Also tried adding `transient { answer ' ' }` to the trait.

Also tried adding `attr_accessor` fields to the `Example` class.

```
class Example
    attr_accessor :questions, :answer
end
```

Comment: Is it the case that the model `has_many :questions`?

Comment: in this case, no, only one question inside that array... this is for an automated test, in the application there could be multiple questions

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question.  The style of factory that you're using implies that this is backed by a specific ActiveRecord model.  My question then would be, is it the case that this particular model support multiple questions in it (even if the test only calls for one right now)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not quite following... am fairly new to Ruby & FactoryGirl. I set up my factory by saying `FactoryGirl.define do` above where my example starts. The `Example` model only contains `attr_accessor :questions, :answer`

Comment: Would you add your model to the question?

Comment: I added the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125009/discussion-between-zmorris-and-makoto).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. With FactoryGirl, when setting an attribute dynamically, you must wrap the attribute in { }. Since this is an array, with a hash inside, the curly braces need to be on the outside of the entire array.

```
factory :example_factory do
  transient do
     ans ''
  end

  user 'TEST'
  id 'blah'
end

trait :example_trait do
questions --> {[
                {
                 question: "blah",
                 answer: ans
                },
              ]} <--
end
```